# Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. any

Tags: typescript, ava

I'm using ava (no link, since I'm not allowed to use more than 2 ) for testing and want to type ava's test context. It's [typed as `any` in ava's definition file](https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/types/base.d.ts#L103).

What I specifically want is that the typescript compiler knows that `t.context` is of the type `{foo: number}` in the following test:

```
import test from 'ava'

test.beforeEach((t) => {
  t.context = { foo: 5 }
})

test('Is context typed', (t) => {
  // uncaught typo
  t.is(t.context.fooo, 5)
})
```

I tried to use [declaration merging](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to do this, but it fails with `TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'context' must be of type 'any', but here has type '{ foo: number; }'.`
:

```
declare module 'ava' {
    interface ContextualTestContext {
      context: {
        foo: number,
      }
    }
}

test.beforeEach((t) => {
  t.context = { foo: 5 }
})

test('Is context typed', (t) => {
  // uncaught ypo
  t.is(t.context.fooo, 5)
})
```

Is there a way to do this without casting the context all the time like so:

```
interface IMyContext {
  foo: number
}

test.beforeEach((t) => {
  t.context = { foo: 5 }
})

test('Is context typed', (t) => {
  const context = <IMyContext> t.context
  // caught typo
  t.is(context.fooo, 5)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing the context will be possible with the next version of ava. Then you can do something like this:

```
import * as ava from 'ava';

function contextualize<T>(getContext: () => T): ava.RegisterContextual<T> {
    ava.test.beforeEach(t => {
        Object.assign(t.context, getContext());
    });

    return ava.test;
}

const test = contextualize(() => {
    return { foo: 'bar' };
});

test.beforeEach(t => {
    t.context.foo = 123; // error:  Type '123' is not assignable to type 'string'
});

test.after.always.failing.cb.serial('very long chains are properly typed', t => {
    t.context.fooo = 'a value'; // error: Property 'fooo' does not exist on type '{ foo: string }'
});

test('an actual test', t => {
    t.deepEqual(t.context.foo.map(c => c), ['b', 'a', 'r']); // error: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'
});
```

If you acquire your context asynchronously you need to change the type signature of `contextualize` accordingly:

```
function contextualize<T>(getContext: () => Promise<T>): ava.RegisterContextual<T> {
    ava.test.beforeEach(async t => {
        Object.assign(t.context, await getContext());
    });

    return ava.test;
}

const test = contextualize(() => {
    const db = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017')

    return { db }
});
```

Otherwise the TypeScript compiler will think `t.context` is a Promise, although it isn't

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way of doing this. In your special case, you could create a new `TestContext`, e.g. instead of

```
export type ContextualTest = (t: ContextualTestContext) => PromiseLike<void> | Iterator<any> | Observable | void;
```

use something like

```
export type MyContextualTest<T> = (t : TestContext & {context : T}) => PromiseLike<void> ...
```

and declare your own `test` function, which should be compatible to Ava's like this:

```
interface MyTestFunction<T> {
    (name : string, run : MyContextualTest<T>)
}

import {test as avaTest} from 'ava';
const test : MyTestFunction<IMyContext> = avaTest;
```

This is mostly untested, so if there are some problems, let me know.

Comment: @despairblue could you raise an issue for your use case? Perhaps we can accept a generic in the `test()` signature.

Comment: @FinnO that works technically, but if I want to use the functions defined on the `test` function itself (like `test.beforeEach`) I would have to redefine all declarations. There are roughly 1700 of them.